# Second HDMI Monitor Not Displaying

Tags: release-loki, display, hdmi

Today, the HDMI port does not seem to be transmitting to the external HDMI monitor I've used for more than a year.  Using fully updated Loki.

I've checked cable connections.  Monitor has power but indicates there is no HDMI signal.

I've power cycled the laptop and monitor multiple times.

I've tried plugging the HDMI cable in before the laptop is powered on.  I've tried waiting to plug it in until I've logged in.

System Settings -> Displays is unaware I have an HDMI monitor plugged in.

I haven't had any external monitor issues in months.  Is there a way to force the OS to detect the monitor?

I've looked at various posts flagged as being similar to this one, but they are all either more than a year old or have no resolution, or in any case none of the suggestions have made any difference.

Comment: Having the same issue but no luck with the power cycle

Answer (score 1):

One more power cycle (full power off and power on) did it (kept HDMI cable plugged in throughout).  It would be nice, however, to have a method that didn't rely on pure luck, as I power cycled several times previously with no effect.  Perhaps xrandr can manually force a state change?